# Getting content of dynamically generated element and put it to 'before parent' element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following code:

```
<input id="from" type="text">
<div id="fromlist">
  <div class="item_element">Value 1</div>
  <div class="item_element">Value 2</div>
</div>
```

All `div`s with class `.item_element` are dynamically generated.

So I need to set the value of `#from` element with the contents of any of .item_element which clicked by the user.

I tried the following:

```
$('.item_element').on('click',function(){alert($(this).contents());});
```

But this code alerts "[object Object]" not a string as I expected.

Furthermore: even if I will get the contents of the `item_element` I don't know how to point to `before parent` element (#from in my case).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need

```
$('#fromlist').on('click', '.item_element', function () {
    console.log($(this).contents());
    $(this).parent().prev().val($(this).text())
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NbNnN/)

---

If you are sure about the input element's id then it is much more simple like

```
$('#fromlist').on('click', '.item_element', function () {
    $('#from').val($(this).text())
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NbNnN/3/)

- The alert will display `[object Object]` because `.contents()` returns a jQuery object which when alerted will display `[Object object]` - use console logging instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation (*as your element is dynamically generated*)

```
$('#fromlist').on('click','.item_element',function(){
   $('#from').val($(this).text());
});
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/ep8R5/1/

`---->`  https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

Try [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$('#fromlist').on('click', '.item_element', function () {
    $(this).closest('#fromlist').prev().val(($(this).text());
});
```